# How can I center an image of *unknown size* in a div, both vertically and horizontally?

Tags: php, html, css

I am looking to handle files that were uploaded by users. The main issue in that situation is that they differ in size.

How can I center an image of unknown size, both vertically and horizontally, into a div?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: I am making a thumbnail for an image. Basically, I want to keep the div to the same size, and I want the image inside that div to fit the div, but without changing the scale. I am using `overflow:hidden`

EDIT:My code is

`<div class='pic'><img id='theimage' src='image.png'></div>`

and my CSS is

```
#theimage {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;

}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to make the div stay a certain size despite the image size? Or are you trying to make the div scale with the image? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I am making a thumbnail for an image. Basically, I want to keep the div to the same size, and I want the image inside that div to fit the div, but without changing the scale. Regards

Comment: Look at the related posts to your question. This is a question asked so many times before. Do some resaerch and you will be much more happy than just copying an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `background` CSS property. Give your `<div>` these properties:

```
div.whatever {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}
```

Then in your HTML (because it's being generated dynamically), add a  `style=""` attribute to the `<div>` with the URL of your image in it:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/path/to/image.png');"></div>
```

You could do this with an `<img>` tag inside the `<div>` too:

```
<div>
    <img src="image.png">
</div>
```

With this CSS (untested, should work):

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}

div img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
}
```

I'm assuming you've given your `<div>` a fixed width and height elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I tried both methods but I can't get it to work, the image is still not centered vertically. I am putting my code in Edit, in moy original post. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Force the container to behave as a table cell.

```
#container {
     display: table-cell; 
     vertical-align: middle; 
     text-align: center;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Am9g9/)

Comment: Hi Starx, your example looks good, but my problem is that most the images that I have to handle will be bigger that the fixed-sized div that I want to use. I tried using `overflow:hidden` with your code but couldn't get it to work? Do you know what's wrong with overflow:hidden? thanks a lot

Comment: @alexx0186, No matter how big the thumbnails are you have to fix their proportions, in order to control them properly. I only fixed the container of the img not everything, just make sure img is constrained, others can go free.

Answer (score -1):

i got a suggestion though this thread is old

try

< div style='text-align:center;overflow:hidden;width:200px;height:200px;' > 
< img src='anypath' width='190'style='vertical-align:middle;display:inline;' />

works just fine ! goodluck